# Entity Framework generates an inner join and an outer join for the same entity

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework

I have the following models.

```
public class Table1
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public string Table1Property {get; set;}
     public int? Table2Id {get; set;}
     public virtual Table2 Table2 {get; set;}
}

public class Table2
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public string Table2Property {get; set;}
     public virtual ICollection<Table1> Table1 {get; set;}
     public int? Table3Id {get; set;}
     public virtual Table3 Table3 {get; set;}
}

public class Table3 
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public virtual ICollection<Table2> Table2 {get; set;}
}
```

These models are made by Entity Framework with database first, and i always need to load all of them. Although i have lazy loading enabled i don't want three queries when it is possible to get them using joins.

If i search with elements form Table1 all is well and it performs like it should.

```
 _dbContext.Table1.Include(x => x.Table2.Table3).Where(x => x.Table1Property == "some string").ToList();
```

This produces the following query.

```
SELECT ....
FFOM Table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.Table2Id = t2.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 t3 on t2.Table3Id = t3.Id
WHERE t1.Table1Property = 'some string'
```

But if i want to search with elements form Table1 and Table2 it gets weird.

```
_dbContext.Table1.Include(x => x.Table2.Table3).Where(x => x.Table1Property == "some string" && x.Table2.Table2Property == "some other string").ToList();
```

This produces this query:

```
SELECT ....
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.Table2Id = t2.Id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 t3 on t2.Id = t3.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 t4 on t3.Table3Id = t4.Id
WHERE t1.Table1Property = 'some string'
AND t2.Table2Property = 'some other string'
```

So it performs two join. An INNER JOIN for the condition and an OUTER JOIN with the same table just to load Table3.

Even if i use the following syntax

```
_dbContext.Table2.Where(x => x.Table2Property == "some string").SelectMany(x => x.Table1).Include(x => x.Table2.Table3).Where(x => x.Table1Property == "some other string").ToList();
```

I get this query

```
SELECT ....
FROM Table2 t1
INNER JOIN Table1 t2 on t1.Table2Id = t2.Id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 t3 on t1.Id = t3.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 t4 on t3.Table3Id = t4.Id
WHERE t1.Table2Property = 'some string'
AND t2.Table1Property = 'some other string'
```

How do i manage to "convince" Entity Framework not to perform the OUTER JOIN and use the INNER JOIN to get Table3?

I use the following assemblies:

- EntityFramework v.6.3.1
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess v12.2.1
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework v12.2.1

Comment: That is due to the Include you used.

Comment: @SubashKharel I know that. But like i said i don't want a second call to the database to get Table3 and that is happening when i don't use Include, and i don't know another way to load related entities [Entity Framework Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: Have you checked the query plan to see if the Oracle query optimizer actually performs the extra join?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Yes it does the extra join.